# Exporting to CSV format incorrect in scrapy

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, export-to-csv

I'm trying out print out a CSV file after scraping using piplines but the formatting is a bit weird because instead of printing it top to bottom it is printing it all at once after scraping page 1 and then all of page 2 in one column. I have attached piplines.py and one line from csv output(quite large). So how do I make to print column wise instead all at once from one page

pipline.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class CSVPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline


    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['names','stars','subjects','reviews']
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

and output.csv

```
names   stars   subjects
Vivek0388,NikhilVashisth,DocSharad,Abhimanyu_swarup,Suresh N,kaushalhkapadia,JyotiMallick,Nitin T,mhdMumbai,SunilTukrel(COLUMN 2)   5 of 5 stars,4 of 5 stars,1 of 5 stars,5 of 5 stars,3 of 5 stars,4 of 5 stars,5 of 5 stars,5 of 5 stars,4 of 5 stars,4 of 5 stars(COLUMN 3) Best Stay,Awesome View... Nice Experience!,Highly mismanaged and dishonest.,A Wonderful Experience,Good place with average front office,Honeymoon,Awesome Resort,Amazing,ooty's beauty!!,Good stay and food
```

It should look something like this

```
Vivek0388      5 of 5
NikhilVashisth 5 of 5
DocSharad      5 of 5
...so on
```

EDIT:

```
items = [{'reviews:':"",'subjects:':"",'names:':"",'stars:':""} for k in range(1000)]
if(sites and len(sites) > 0):
    for site in sites:
        i+=1
        items[i]['names'] = item['names']
        items[i]['stars'] = item['stars']
        items[i]['subjects'] = item['subjects']
        items[i]['reviews'] = item['reviews']
        yield Request(url="http://tripadvisor.in" + site, callback=self.parse)
    for k in  range(1000):
        yield items[k]
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I have changed the settings

Comment: You know, that your scraper stores all names as a list in your item? (I remember it from yesterday's question). Try to split every entry to its separate item to get the results you want. And the same goes for all your entries: one item of yours is a list of items.

Comment: I tried that with no avail all I got was a blank document. Becuase whatever i define in my spider It gets called no matter what. But I think Im going to convert to JSON and then Have it convert to CSV because Im more used to that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem but as I said, you should take care of these results in the Spider itself and then it will work like a charm.

Comment: I tried that but I keep on getting error saying that I need to return Item/Field() I tried returning a dict but I got an error again. Also did not work as its a recursive call thus it will redefine the dict erasing it. But I will try once again and do what you said.

Comment: In worst case you can find me and ask for advice. The solution is not as bad as it seems :)

Comment: Ok so I have made a change to my code,  I couldn't find a split method for the Field()

Comment: Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163023/export-csv-file-from-scrapy-not-via-command-line/25165414#25165414. You'll have to add logic of what fields to write though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, csv zip it and then for loop it through it and write row. This was MUCH less complicated once you read the docs.

```
import csv
import itertools

class CSVPipeline(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
      self.csvwriter.writerow(['names','starts','subjects','reviews'])

   def process_item(self, item, ampa):

      rows = zip(item['names'],item['stars'],item['subjects'],item['reviews'])


      for row in rows:
         self.csvwriter.writerow(row)

      return item
```