# Can I export data I have scraped from a website to a csv file in python?

Tags: api, csv, spyder

I have scraped data from the NBA website using an API in Spyder, but I want to write the data I have scraped into a CSV file. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have your data stored in an array like this for example: `arr = [["data","data","some more data"],["data",...],...]`

a way to store this in an csv file would be as simple as:

```
with open("../data/file.csv", "w", encoding="utf8", newline='') as csvfile:
    file = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for x in arr:
         file.writerow(x)
```

where "../data/file.csv" is the location you want to store the csv file and
"w" is for the action you want to do. In this case writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways.
1. command line
2. code

Please have a look here.
[Export csv file from scrapy (not via command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163023/export-csv-file-from-scrapy-not-via-command-line)